# Javascript - How to avoid if statements like the snippet given below?

Tags: javascript, polymorphism

How to avoid the if statements as in the below snippet, since there could have been multiple ifs to be checked and the whole code would have looked quite messy. Is there a polymorphic mechanism that could be effectively adopted here? Additionally, Please refer a link to understand polymorphism in javascript if you have one.

```
function car(type) {
  this.type = type;
  this.shout = function() {
    if(this.type == "automatic")
      alert("automatic type");
    else if(this.type == "manual")
      alert("manual type");
  };
}

var audi = new car("manual");
audi.shout();
```

Comment: You can also implement factory to create different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the mappings in an associative array:

```
var carTypes = {};
carTypes["automatic"] = "automatic type";
carTypes["manual"] = "manual type";
```

Which you can then lookup :

```
this.shout = function() {
    alert(carTypes[this.type]);
  };
```

Some validation will be required to ensure that the keys of the array are constrained.

Comment: Is your code abiding with polymorphic behaviour? Just a question.

Comment: No, there's nothing OO polymorphic about this, its just an efficient mechanism to answer your title question `How to avoid if statements like the code snippets below?` :)

Comment: @StuartLS - Ok, Is there a way to apply polymorphism for above snippet?

Comment: (Inheritance) Polymorphicism would require that you subclass car into `manualCar` and `automaticCar`, and then override (or just replace) the shout function accordingly (or better, implement a `getTransmissionType()` function, implemented by both subclasses, which is called by a common inherited `shout`). This also seems to be rather overkill in the given example?